# JSON WCF Security

Tags: wcf, json

Are JSON enabled  WCF service secured as they carry Human readable strings
Any article on JSON enabled WCF secrity will help.(link)

Answer (score 2):

JSON-enabled WCF services are REST-based - those basically transmit everythign in clear text, so in order to get any protection against snooping, you'd have to secure the transport layer using e.g. SSL encryption.

Marc

Comment: So does it have to anything with binding ..
As using WSbindings with JSON WCF calls will make my call more secure..

Comment: No - just using wsHttpBinding will not make your calls more secure - what you need to do is enable transport-level security (SSL). You can do this in both BasicHttp as well as wsHttpBindings.

Answer (score 0):

WCF is just a framework to make communcation simpler, it doesn't in and by itself make anything secure.

JSON is just a nice way to transmit data, esp when sending to a webpage, as it can be more compact than xml, and javascript can parse JSON faster than xml since JSON is made for javascript.

If you have any sensitive information you can either encrypt that specific data or you can just use SSL connections, but that can impact performance.